# How to cast object to a class knowing only the class name?

Tags: c#, .net, types

I am a C# NewBie and I'm in a situation where i know the type of the object (ClassName) in

```
ObservableCollection<ClassName>
```

and now i need to use it to cast returning object of the same thats comes as an

```
ObservableCollection<object>
```

how do i do somethign like

`ObservableCollection<type>` where type s the Type of ClassName? is it possible when i have the type of the ClassName i can use it instead of the ClassName if not how do i achive it?

Comment: your question is quite vague. Please elaborate. Do you want to cast an IEnumerable to ObservableCollection<ClassName>?

Answer (score 1):

Generic parameters on concrete classes are never co-variant. And on interface they can only be variant if they are either used as input or output parameter, but never both.

So you can't ever cast `ObservableCollection<T>` to `ObservableCollection<object>`.

Check out [Covariance and Contravariance in Generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd799517.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your wording, do you mean you want:

```
typeof(ClassName)
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
return new ObservableCollection<object>(myClassNameObservableCollection);
```

Answer (score 0):

From the last sentence of your question I guess you need that

[Type.MakeGenericType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype.aspx)

So you can do something like that:

```
Type generic = typeof(ObservableCollection<>);
Type[] typeArgs = { typeof(ClassName) };
Type constructed = generic.MakeGenericType(typeArgs);
var obj = Activator.CreateInstance(constructed);
```